# Parse array inside array,

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

I am trying to parse an array inside an array... this is what i have tried and worked, i got the info for "kjennemerke" but not a childarray = "dekkdimensjon" couldt find anything releated  on stack that worked.

```
   <?php
$jsonData=file_get_contents(filelocation);
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData,true);

$record=$phpArray['kjennemerke'];
print_r($record);
?>
```

but i am trying to get **"dekkdimensjon"**

https://textuploader.com/1a8qj/raw

Comment: I don't know what is your problem... you want to get this? ```$phpArray['tekniskKjoretoy']['aksler']['dekkOgFelger'][0]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accessing the correct index.

Here is one way you can access your data for `dekkdimensjon`.

```
$jsonData=file_get_contents(filelocation);
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData,true);

foreach($phpArray['tekniskKjoretoy']['aksler']['dekkOgFelger'] as $k=>$v){
    echo $v['dekkdimensjon'];
}
```

or if you would like to group all of these values in their own array:

```
$values = array_column($phpArray['tekniskKjoretoy']['aksler']['dekkOgFelger'], 'dekkdimensjon');
```

Comment: how would i go about adding them to a list like so: https://gyazo.com/0dd520ae176c7336a9fa9cdcca2b601f

Comment: @Root, Depends on how you would like to do that, it could be as simple as `echo`'ing the data from PHP as HTML elements, ie: `echo "<div>{$k} | {$v}</div>"` (you can do this in the loop above).

Comment: Sorry, try `echo "<div>{$k} | {$v['dekkdimensjon']}</div>"`. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks, any way i can seperate the 2 lines that contains 235/65R18?

Comment: One list for the first two lines (0,1)

Comment: Yes, you can filter the array (ie: `array_filter()`) or you can echo out your elements only if the line contains `'235/65R18'` (ie: `if($v['dekkdimensjon']==='235/65R18'){/* echo here. */}`)